# Userform2.initialize where textbox1.value = combobox1.value from userform1

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, textbox, userform

I have two userforms. In userform1 the script that sets the value of "x" is:

```
Private Sub Combobox1_Change()
    x = Combobox1.Value + 2
End Sub
```

I need userform2 to initialize with textbox1.value = x from userform1.

I don't even know where to start on this one. Any insight on how to do this?

EDIT: I'm trying the code below for userform2:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    x = userform1.combobox1.Value
    textbox1.Value = x
End Sub
```

The userform initializes fine, but the textbox1.Value working.

Comment: I think you don't have to have `Private Sub Combobox1_Change()` in UserForm1, but in UserForm2 initialize, have the line something like this `textbox1.Value = userform1.combobox1.Value + 2`

Comment: Where and how do you call `userform2`? You should also show this code. BUT, in most cases it is not a good idea to call the [default instance](https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/userforms_advanced_tips.html) of a userform in another userform. Maybe it is even easier to work with one userfrom and use frames, multipages or soemthing like that. The user won't even notice that he still uses the same userform.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value from the combobox directly. It will have the values even if it is not visible any more.

UserForm2:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.TextBox1.Value = UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value + 2
End Sub
```

I also wrote to test it:
In a Modul:

```
Sub test()
    UserForm1.Show 'I just had a fix value in the combobox for the test
    UserForm2.Show
End Sub
```